# How can i Select number of rows based on unique id?

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables.

A

```
Shop_id     numbers
916TC           3   
RKTCR           2   
LSTCR           1
WBSTC           4
BHTTC           2
KFCTC           2
```

B

```
numbers Price   
1        100rs
2        150rs  
3        200rs  
4        300rs
```

i want to get output as

```
 Shop_id Price
    916TC  100rs
    916TC  150rs
    916TC  200rs
```

numbers=3.

```
 Shop_id    Price
    LSTCR    100rs
```

as numbers=1

```
Shop_id Price
KFCTC    100rs
KFCTC    150rs
```

as numbers=2,

since with that Shop_id corresponds to numbers,
pls Help me with the SQL query to make this possible

Comment: You can use JOIN and WHERE.

Comment: could you please tell me the whole query @KostasMitsarakis

Comment: `select count(*) from table where id = whatever`. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/counting-rows.html

Comment: Please define better what you want as output. Do you want a single number or the resulted rows?

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/ --- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins

Comment: i want resultant rows guys@KostasMitsarakis

Comment: How do you get 3 rows when the shop is `916TC`?

Comment: @chris85 it looks like the OP wants to join `x` number of rows table `B` to table `A`, based off the value of `numbers` in table `A`. So with `916TC` having a value of `3` for numbers, they want to join rows `1`,`2`, and `3` from table `B`.

Comment: as numbers = 3,in B.Ohhh.I think my way of table implementation is not best.pls suggest inorder to get 3 rows when shop is 916TC.pls @chris85

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a simple `JOIN` query, with your condition in the `ON` being that you want all rows `<=` to the numbers value

```
SELECT Shop_id, Price
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B
ON B.numbers <= A.numbers
WHERE A.Shop_id = ?
```

with `?` representing your specific `Shop_id`

[sqlFiddle example - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/972cc/2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/972cc/2)

Comment: when i run with A.Shop_id="916TC" i get                                           Shop_id Price
916TC 100rs       ................                                                                                                                                                                                                Shop_id   Price
    916TC  100rs
    916TC  150rs
    916TC  200rs  is what i want. @Sean

Comment: That is not what you get with my query, as evident in the [sqlFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/972cc/2). What does your php code look like? Most likely you are doing a `fetch_assoc()` or `->fetch()`, which just returns **1** row, which you will need to do in a loop, ie. `while($row = fetch_assoc(...)){ ... }`. That is a very common mistake/error for new coders.

Comment: `...WHERE Shops.Shop_id ='LSTCR';` -> well `LSTCR` in your sample code is `LSTCR, 1`, so it should only return **1** row. how many does it return?

Comment: it returns 3.since it appears 3rd in row!...

Comment: You have edited [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33722102/how-can-i-select-number-of-rows-based-on-unique-id#comment55215256_33722400) so it is hard to follow what your issue is.

Comment: Well that is because you are doing `ON B.ID <= Shops.id`. Clearly you gave us a bastardized sample of your tables/code, so we could not clearly help you. What column is `numbers` in your `Shops` table? It should be something like `ON B.ID <= Shops.numbers`, but I can't help more than that because of your ambiguities.

Comment: cool!..It worked.Thanks @Sean

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Shop_id, Price
FROM TableA, TableB
WHERE TableA.numbers = TableB.numbers
```

Comment: I think that it's a bad idea to comma separate tables in FROM clause. Use explicit JOINs instead.

Comment: Not what i want as Output :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/997e0/2)

```
SELECT aa.Shop_id, bb.Price
FROM A AS aa
INNER JOIN B AS bb
ON aa.numbers = bb.numbers
WHERE aa.numbers = 3;
```

Result:

```
Shop_id Price
916TC   200rs
```

Comment: Shop_id Price
    916TC  100rs
    916TC  150rs
    916TC  200rs This should be the output i expect.(First 3 rows from B table)

Comment: Oh, i see. Then I suppose @Sean answer suits you.